# Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead again

Tags: python

Following line of code:
`df_under['Work Ratio']=df_under['Work Ratio'].astype(float)` 
is generating *Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead* warning.
How to get rid of it?

Thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a pandas dataframe and you would like to change the data type of the column 'Work Ratio'? The warning tells you that by changing `df_under['Work Ratio']` you will not change the actual dataframe in place. The warning tells you to access the column by saying

```
df_under.loc[:,'Work Ratio']=df_under['Work Ratio'].astype(float) #all rows, column 'Work Ratio'
```

Alternatively you could save the data types of your dataframe

```
col_types = df_under.dtypes
```

which gives you a pandas series of types. Now change the type of 'Work Ratio'

```
col_types['Work Ratio'] = float
```

and change the whole dataframe as

```
df_under = df_under.astype(col_types)
```